# Storing logs on per day basis in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, clustering

Requirements here are to store historical logs.

For the sake of simplicity I'll assume this sample scenario where we are selling some products on our website and we need to keep records of sales of every product made by a salesman on a per day basis. Number of Salesman and Products are known and constant.

Now, Say we have 3 products for sale, *Laptop*, *coffee-mug* and *pen*.
Here I have this table to keep record of sales for today (Live records, which will be updated throughout the day)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sales_record (
    id SERIAL,
    salesman_id INT NOT NULL,
    sold_laptop INT NOT NULL,
    sold_mugs INT NOT NULL,
    sold_pen INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

And another table to keep records of old data

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sales_record_log (
    id SERIAL,
    salesman_id INT NOT NULL,
    sold_laptop INT NOT NULL,
    sold_mugs INT NOT NULL,
    sold_pen INT NOT NULL,
    record_for_day TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Having this up and running, all we need to do is keep updating the recordset and increment proper column by 1 for every sale.

Problem we are experiencing with this setup is that it is necessary to move data from live table to another table at the end of every day and flush the **sold_*** records from live table, like this:

```
INSERT INTO sales_record_log
    (salesman_id, sold_laptop, sold_mugs, sold_pen)
        SELECT salesman_id, sold_laptop, sold_mugs, sold_pen
        FROM sales_record;

UPDATE sales_record SET sold_laptop = 0, sold_pen = 0, sold_mugs = 0;
```

To automate the process of logging, moving data and cleaning up, I was looking into a possible situation with Table cluster in PostgreSQL and Triggers to automatically update a descendant table whenever a new record is inserted into parent table, but I cant seem to find a way to synchronize proper records on every `UPDATE` on *Live* table and then check whether the *Log* table has a record for today, If yes then Update proper column else Insert a new row and then Update the value.
Keeping in mind that there can be a salesman who has not made any sale for several days, when He make a sale after 5 days, *Log* table will have no record for this salesman regarding those 5 days when no sale was made.

I have a strong feeling that there can be much better setup than this but I am all clueless. can anyone please help me setting it up or guide me if I am doing it the wrong way ?

## Edit

---

I decided to maintain both Live and Old records in same table and choose the Old-Record's table structure for it, with slight modifications in `PRIMARY KEY` i.e.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sales_record (
    id SERIAL,
    salesman_id INT NOT NULL,
    sold_laptop INT NOT NULL,
    sold_mugs INT NOT NULL,
    sold_pen INT NOT NULL,
    record_for_day DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (salesman_id, record_for_day)
);
```

Please notice the changes in `PRIMARY KEY` and Data Type of record_for_day column.

Now, I Insert the data with this **UPSERT** like function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_log(salesman INT,
                           laptops INT DEFAULT 0,
                           mugs INT DEFAULT 0,
                           pens INT DEFAULT 0,
                           for_day DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
RETURNS VOID AS
'
BEGIN
    LOOP
        UPDATE sales_record SET
            sold_laptop = sold_laptop + laptops,
            sold_mugs = sold_mugs + mugs,
            sold_pen = sold_pen + pens
            WHERE salesman_id = salesman AND record_for_day = for_day;

        IF found THEN
            RETURN;
        END IF;

        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO sales_record
                (salesman_id, sold_laptop, sold_mugs, sold_pen, record_for_day)
            VALUES
                (salesman, laptop, mugs, pens, for_day);
            RETURN;

            EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
                -- Encountered only if someone else has inserted the record in meantime
                -- In that case, lets loop and try to update again
        END;
    END LOOP;
END;
'
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Trying to INSERT

```
SELECT * FROM sales_record;

0 Records

SELECT update_log(2, 1, 0, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

SELECT * FROM sales_record;

+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id  | salesman_id | sold_laptop | sold_mugs | sold_pen |   for_day  |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1   |    2        |    1        |    0      |   0      | 18/02/2013 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+

SELECT update_log(2, 0, 1, 2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id  | salesman_id | sold_laptop | sold_mugs | sold_pen |   for_day  |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1   |    2        |    1        |    1      |   1      | 18/02/2013 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+

SELECT update_log(32, 0, 1, 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

SELECT * FROM sales_record;

+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id  | salesman_id | sold_laptop | sold_mugs | sold_pen |   for_day  |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 2   |    32       |    0        |    1      |   1      | 18/02/2013 |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1   |    2        |    1        |    1      |   1      | 18/02/2013 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Better than CRON, Triggers or Rules but still not satisfactory.
I know I am acting too greedy, but guys, Who dont want more ?

It looks more like a hack to me, it might fail at some point of time though I have not tested it.

I am still open to suggestions.

Comment: You don't mention quite important point here: what is the purpose of this design? Performance boost for the “current” records? Simple ease of data administration? Anything else?

Comment: @vyegorov Purpose of this design is to keep track of sales for administrator and salesman to view whenever they want it, you can say that the historical records will be accessed as frequently (or more) as live records.

Comment: @vyegorov I have updated the question with a little more research work.

Comment: How do you store your 'real' order data?  How many orders do you expect daily?

Comment: @dezso we dont actually sells anything, It was an example scenario that just happens to match with ours. anyway, there can be a couple thousand insertions in a day if I talk about the real problem. same can be said for reading records, a couple thousand Select per day.

Comment: @dezso, Could you please post your ideas as an answer ? I'm desperately looking for a proper way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

The best option IMO is to use a cron job to generate the logs for 'yesterday'::date.  You could also use triggers before insert/update/delete to update the other table but this adds complexity and overhead, and for the current day, but this gets pretty complicated.  Generate your historical logs once the data won't change anymore.

In this case you write a sql query and run it via psql and cron.

I would also add a trigger denying update or delete to records covered in your historical data if you can.

This gives you a few benefits:

1. It is more obvious when it breaks
2. It is simpler, with simpler failure cases

Now, as per your concerns:

1. You say you need rows for every day.  This can be handled a number of relatively easy ways in PostgreSQL (remember that dates support integer math so you can take a base date and add a series to it, to generate a date series).  This is a pretty easy way to get around if you are generating rows per day of week, etc.
2. You say you cant guarantee things won't change.  The key question here is what your change window is and to do your historical reports after this window has closed.  For example if it is after a month, you can generate reports for all dates in a month a month prior (i.e. generate all dates in January during early March).  You can then rely on a view to handle newer rows vs older rows in a live basis.  You can then have a trigger which ensures that the date of an inserted row in the orders table is newer than the newest date in the other table.

In my experience worrying about keeping this as a live summary *usually* isn't necessary.  Small organizations (with small data sets) tend to close out books at least once a year, and live reporting is an option there.  Larger organizations with larger data sets tend to close out receivables and payables (i.e. invoices) once a month or so, and so the only areas that have to be reported live (because they are subject to adjustment or revision) are open orders (which can be revised) and invoices which may need to be reviewed occasionally (and should never be revised but may have adjustments issued against them which might or might not need to be tracked in such a system).

Comment: Let me add that (if I understand correctly) this method implies the orders being stored individually with `salesman_id` and a timestamp of the purchase.  I'd say that unless the OP has a high number of purchases daily, a report of the current day and one for past data would be a cleaner and easier solution.

Comment: There are several cases of failure in this approach, first and foremost, The days with no sales will be skipped from being recorded. secondly, we cant assure that the records wont change anymore after the data has been exported from live-records table to old-records table.

Comment: @dezso I just have update the question if you want to take a look

Comment: I have updated to discuss your concerns.